# Error: Could not get input duration, please specify fixed timemarks

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using the fluent-ffmpeg module for Node.js to generate screenshot.

I have used following snippet to achieve this -

```
var filePath = "../app/webroot/img/uploads/video/50_1429701765.mp4";
var destFolder = "../app/webroot/img/uploads/video/screenshots";
var fileName = "screenshots.png";
generateScreenshot(filePath, fileName, destFolder);
function generateScreenshot(filePath, fileName, destFolder) {

    ffmpeg(filePath)
            .screenshots({
                timestamps: ['01%'],
                filename: fileName,
                folder: destFolder,
                size: '320x240'
            });

}
```

But i am getting an error like below-

```
Error: Could not get input duration, please specify fixed timemarks
    at /var/www/html/tcpapi/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/recipes.js:182:29
    at /var/www/html/tcpapi/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/recipes.js:162:11
```

Though i have already set the timemarks, screenshot not generated from this.

Anyone have any suggestion to get rid from this error.

Thanks

Comment: That error means it cannot calculate the duration of the video, meaning you have to input fixed timestamps. EG: `['01:10.123', '01:20.123']`.

Comment: i have already tried out with all possible parameters, but not succeed.

Comment: You can't proceed with using percentages, unless ffmpeg can calculate the length of the video.

Comment: i have used ['01:10.123'] but not working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fluent-ffmpeg module some drawbacks still exists. So they provide an alternate solution to overcome. It really help those who are facing issue like i have mentioned in question.

You can install module's newer version in your app through following command

```
npm i fluent-ffmpeg-extended
```

for more detail you can see newer [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg-extended) of module

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got that error because i was StreamWriting from youtube, so when i got the video from the path it was in different format, make sure your video file is correct using ffprobe like this:

```
ffmpeg.ffprobe(path_to_video,function(err,metadata){
  console.log("Metadata: ",metadata)
})
```

It also generates inputs on ffmpeg which are used to make the screenshot, thumbnails and others.

Probably you need to set ffprobe path:

```
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath('D:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe');
```

And then before get metadata get the probe path:

```
ffmpeg()._getFfprobePath(function(err, path) { console.log("error ffprobe",err);console.log("path",path) })
```